# PDFkit adding content on a new page

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, pdfkit

I'm generating pdf with data from database. It works fine until there is too much data which do not fit on the first page. How do I create new page when the first one is full and continue adding data on new page?

**Function to generate inner**

```
function generateInnerPdf(doc, missions) {
  generateHeader(doc, missions);
  generateTableRow(
    doc,
    tableStartPos,
    'Název mise',
    'Uav',
    'GPS',
    'Doba letu',
    'Teplota',
    'Vítr',
    'Start mise',
    'Konec mise',
    'Použité baterie',
    'Popis'
  );
  generateHr(doc, tableStartPos + 45);
  generateBody(doc, missions);
  generateFooter(doc);
}
```

**Function to generate body**

```
function generateBody(doc, missions) {
  for (i = 0; i < missions.length; i++) {
    const item = missions[i];
    let position = tableStartPos + (i + 1) * 60;

    generateTableBody(
      doc,
      position,
      item.missionName,
      item.uav,
      item.gps,
      item.flightTime,
      item.tmp,
      item.wind,
      moment(item.missionStart).format('lll'),
      moment(item.missionEnd).format('lll'),
      item.usedBatteries,
      item.desc
    );
  }
}
```

**Generate table body**

```
function generateTableBody(doc, y, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10) {
  doc
    .fontSize(10)
    .text(c1, 50, y)
    .text(c2, 150, y)
    .text(c3, 250, y)
    .text(`${c4} min`, 480, y)
    .moveDown()
    .text(`${c5} °C`, 50, y + 15)
    .text(`${c6} m/s`, 150, y + 15)
    .text(c7, 250, y + 15)
    .text(c8, 450, y + 15)
    .text(c9, 50, y + 30)
    .text(c10, 150, y + 30);
}
```

When there is too much data, it creates a lot of pages with random data all around. How to solve it. Thank you!

[Output range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RLcU.png) it adds everytime 10 pages

EDIT: Tried this condition

```
 if (position > 650) {
      doc.addPage();
      position = 130;
    }
```

But it adds every new record on a new page

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

```
function generateBody(doc, missions) {
  let index = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < missions.length; i++) {
    const item = missions[i];
    let position = tableStartPos + index * 60;
    index++;
    if (position > 650) {
      index = 0;
      tableStartPos = 20;
      doc.addPage();
    }
    generateTableBody(
      doc,
      position,
      item.missionName,
      item.uav,
      item.gps,
      item.flightTime,
      item.tmp,
      item.wind,
      moment(item.missionStart).format('lll'),
      moment(item.missionEnd).format('lll'),
      item.usedBatteries,
      item.desc
    );
  }
}
```